# Converting a twisted consumer into a Service

Tags: rabbitmq, twisted, pika

I'm trying to get a twisted-based pika (RabbitMQ) consumer into a service. Here's the relevant bits of what I've put in place currently:

**worker.py**

```
import pika
from pika.adapters import twisted_connection
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor, protocol, task

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run(connection):
    channel = yield connection.channel()
    yield channel.queue_declare(
        queue='event_queue',
        durable=True, auto_delete=False, exclusive=False
    )
    queue_object, consumer_tag = yield channel.basic_consume(
        queue='event_queue', no_ack=False
    )
    l = task.LoopingCall(process, queue_object, connection)
    l.start(0.01)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def process(queue_object, connection):
    ch, method, properties, body = yield queue_object.get()
    if body:
         print "Do stuff here"
    yield ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

def start():
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters()
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(
        reactor, twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection, parameters
    )
    d = cc.connectTCP(MQ_SERVER, MQ_SERVER_PORT)
    d.addCallback(lambda x: x.ready)
    d.addCallback(run)
```

This worker works just fine when run using the following script :

**runserver.py**

```
import worker
from twisted.internet import reactor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker.start()
    reactor.run()
```

I can't see to figure out how to get this to work with other Services in a .tac file.

**services.tac**

```
from twisted.application import service
application = service.Application("An application")


from other import get_service
other_service = get_service()
other_service.setServiceParent(application)

import worker
worker.start()
```

This tac file doesn't work when it's run. The same code without other service seems to work, but it doesn't seem to work when there are other services enabled. Instead, it returns a timed out deferred.

Is there a way I can turn this connectTCP thing which takes deffereds into a regular service?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a `.tac` file with twistd:

```
$ twistd -ny services.tac
```

Comment: Yes, I do do that. Well, systemd runs a script which runs twistd -ny services.tac. It works when there's only one of these connectTCP type service alone, or when there's any number of other TCPServer based, well defined services (from twisted standard or based on similar libraries). It breaks when I try to put them into the same .tac.

Comment: A complete example is often required before anyone can understand the situation and provide a correct answer.  Consider adding all of the missing information about what you're doing to your question.